# How to access an IEnumerable of model from script in razor pages in MVC?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, razor-pages

Is there any way to access a collection of model from java script in MVC? I want to get them and add some kind of style based on some value for each of them. I know how to handle it once you are dealing with one  model.

```
@model Model


@section Scripts{
    <script>
var model = "@Model";
</script>
}
```

But for an IEnumerable of model I failed. I tried something like below;

```
@model IEnumerable<Model>

@section Scripts{
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
$("@Model").each(function(model){
alert(model);

});
</script>
}
```

Comment: Could you  share  what you want to show about dealing with one model? I don't know what you want to do with  IEnumerable of model and what's error you get .

Comment: @QingGuo I have an IEnumerable of products in this razor page. I want to check some value for each of them and add some class based on that value. Something like below; const card = document.getElementById("card"); if (someValue){ card.style.color = 'blue'};  I want to iterate through the model and check that value for each of them.

Comment: JavaScript knows nothing about .NET objects. You need to convert the `IEnumerable` to something that JavaScript can work with, such as JSON.